# Identity does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to upgrade from MVC6 beta (6.0.0-rc1-final) to latest ASP.NET Core 1.0.0

I managed to upgrade my application using asp.net documentation help.

But now, when I run my application using CTRL+F5, it gives me error for /Views/_ViewImports.cshtml file-

> "The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore'"

[Complete error snap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFaLT.png)

Below is my global.json-

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Apex",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "gulp-sass": "2.1.1",
    "node-sass": "3.4.2"
  }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": ""
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "",

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc",
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using MVC6_Full_Version
@using MVC6_Full_Version.Models
@using MVC6_Full_Version.ViewModels.Account
@using MVC6_Full_Version.ViewModels.Manage
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration
```

If you see my `_ViewImports.cshtml` file above, it has Identity namespace.

Please guide me on this how to resolve this runtime error.

My environment is- VS2015 community edition and ASP.NET core1.0 and .NET framework 4.6.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `dotnet restore`?

Comment: yes...but no luck! I can see Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in my reference and my project is building successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `"preserveCompilationContext": true` in your `project.json`

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
```

See if this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

`preserveCompilationContext` is required when you are using Razor or any other type of runtime compiling. Without it, runtime compilation of Razor views will fail.

For more information refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#buildoptions).

Comment: I will try. but what does this means?

Comment: Anyone know how to set this in VS 2017 .csproj?